# How does NIPALS algorithm work?

Tags: pca, algorithms, eigenvalues, numerics

I'm working on NIPALS algorithm and I found this procedure from [here](http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=MSPC/NIPALSTechnicalNotes):

[image]

I'm just confused with the 4th step which stated, "using the $k$th scores, re-estimate the eigenvalues". As I understand, NIPALS constructs the scores and loadings directly without using eigen-decomposition. Could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: It's actually a disguised implementation of the usual power method for finding the dominant eigenvalue (and corresponding eigenvector) of a symmetric matrix; or, recouched in SVD terms, finding the left and right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value.